# Error in joining tables and displaying the difference in the average check when using Pandas and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Task: There are two tables:

rides (order_id, user_id, order_dt, order_cost) - all rides in Uber.
users (user_id, gender) - table of users, where the gender of the user (M/F) is marked
Need to:

Calculate the difference in the average check for M/F users for a certain period (any way in SQL, Python).

Explain why it might be different.

I solved it in two ways, but they write to me that there is an error and they don’t say where and in what exactly (maybe in the logic of the solution).

Help me find.

My solution:

Python

```
import pandas as pd

taxi = pd.read_csv('taxi.csv')
users = pd.read_csv('users.csv')

df = pd.merge(taxi, users, on='user_id')

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2022-01-01')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2022-12-31')
df = df[(df['order_dt'] >= start_date) & (df['order_dt'] <= end_date)]

result = df.groupby('gender')['order_cost'].mean()

diff = result.loc['М'] - result.loc['F']

print(diff)
```

SQL

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN gender = 'М' THEN order_cost ELSE END) AS avg_cost_male,
       AVG(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN order_cost ELSE END) AS avg_cost_female,
       AVG(CASE WHEN gender = 'М' THEN order_cost ELSE END) - AVG(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' 
THEN order_cost ELSE 0 END) AS diff
FROM taxi
JOIN users ON taxi.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE order_dt BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL code, else of case clause should be NULL instead of 0, otherwise, it will average out the cost to both Male and Female.

See the following code as an example:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN gender = 'М' THEN order_cost ELSE NULL END) AS avg_cost_male,
       AVG(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' THEN order_cost ELSE NULL END) AS avg_cost_female,
       AVG(CASE WHEN gender = 'М' THEN order_cost ELSE NULL END) - AVG(CASE WHEN gender = 'F' 
THEN order_cost ELSE NULL END) AS diff
FROM taxi
JOIN users ON taxi.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE order_dt BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-12-31';
```